# timing of constraints application

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints

I have a `UIView` in which I display a movie if a particular chapter demands it. This view is resized via constraints in `Main.storyboard` to adapt to iPhone. All works fine on iPad. It also works fine on iPhone unless the app is asked to reload when a movie containing chapter was last active meaning that a movie will be first-up on loading. In this scenario, the movie is loaded into the iPad dimensions instead of the smaller iPhone specs.

It appears that the constraints on the movie's view are not engaged in a timely manner. The issue centers on a query of the the view's bounds. If I insert a delay before using the bounds the issue goes away. In fact, a delay of 0.0 seconds does the job!

Using a kludge that relies on a delay seems pretty funky to me.  I can also move the call that uses the bounds to `viewDidLoad` to resolve the issue but then I see some underlying “garbage” when reloading the app, the launch image seemingly not in effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you're using `bounds` before your views have been lain out. Without actually seeing your code, I would suggest executing your described code inside of `viewDidLayoutSubViews`.

Comment: Thanks! I've never had recourse to use this, it appears to be what's needed here.

Comment: I'll make it an answer so this question can be officially resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using `bounds` before your views have been lain out. Without actually seeing your code, I would suggest executing your described code inside of `viewDidLayoutSubViews()`.